# QDialog missing border

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qdialog

When I try to display a QDialog it appears in the top left corner of my screen with no border. The content is correct rendered but the border is missing.

Even if i all kind of WindowHint's and WindowType's like Qt::Widget, Qt::Dialog or Qt::WindowTitleHint =>  Nothing changed!

Thanks for any hints!

**EDIT**: I try the same SW with Windows and in works (maybe a ifdef makes the difference ...)

---

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

QT: 5.6.1

MyDialog.cpp

```
MyDialog::MyDialog(MyDialog::MyDialogTypes type, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent) ,
    ui(new Ui::MyDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setDialogType(type);
}
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
bool MainWindow::confirm() 
{
    MyDialog dlg(MyDialog::Type1, this);
    dlg.setWindowTitle("ABC");

    return dlg.exec() != QDialog::Accepted
}
```

Comment: On linux, for normal Qt you need to have a window manager running which renders the frames and is responsible for resizing and positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution. It was outside the code. One of my colleagues change the Ubuntu config to force my application as full screen. So not only the main window was full screen but also all other windows and message boxes. We changed this and it works.

I don't want so remove this question in order some other readers have the same problem (or the same nice colleagues :-) )

Answer (score 0):

You can set the border width by code by calling `setContentMargins` on the layout. For example:

```
ui->myQDialog->setContentsMargins(3,3,3,3); // sets the qdialog border width to 3px.
```

Comment: @Sirius Windows border and layout margins are different. Your code will only set margins for layout.